# Using GCP Console, In bigquery save query result as bigquery table not working

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Once I clicked "Save Result" and select save as "Bigquery Table" and finally clicked "Export" button. No response from the GCP Console and no table is saved.

[snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHXZL.png)

Comment: Did you check the bigquery logs?

Comment: of course yes, but no log was captured when I hit export button to save the query result as table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same problem - sent a feedback about it, for now if you disable editor tabs, the export works properly. To disable them you just click "Disable editor tabs" in upper left menu
[image: Image of menu UI]